# Slow Kiln ( Tezos ) to Update Node from Snapshot

Tags: node, baking, kiln

First I installed Kiln on a VM. It was all perfect and updated the node in about 1 hour. Then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer and Kiln takes forever to update the node from the snapshot. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting your question.

First, you may already be aware that the OVA file is an **alpha release**, so you may run into issues or features that aren't quite as good as other releases, such as the .deb file. I have seen the OVA instance be resource constrained in the past, depending on the specifications of the VM you are running it in.

That said, I think there are two shortcomings of snapshot import with Kiln's OVA file effective v0.7.2.

1. There is no user feedback on the snapshot import, such as a progress bar. This can make the import process frustrating if it starts taking a while because you don't know if it is almost finished, if it hit an error, etc.
2. The snapshot import cannot be cancelled. So if it fails, you have to start Kiln from a fresh start. There's also no feedback to the user to inform them the import has failed. This can be frustrating.

I think #2 is the worse of these two, and v0.7.3 will allow imports to be cancelled. #1 is something we should address shortly after that.

For now, I would recommend giving the snapshot import a few hours for OVA. If you've already done that, unfortunately you may need to start fresh with a new installation. To maximize your chances of success, I also recommend making sure your machine doesn't fall asleep while doing the import and you've got ample resources allocated to the VM. v0.7.3 should be released by 2019-11-22.

Best of luck!

Comment: I have the Kiln v0.7.2 node updated on PC and would like to know if it is possible to copy the data to another PC that is not

Comment: It is possible to copy data, but you have to be careful of many things. Its always better to import a recent snapshot and let the node sync on its own.